# Groupbox borders

Tags: qt, widget, border, ubuntu-10.04, invisible

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 64 bit and QT 4.6.3. QGroupBox borders in any Qt Application are not visible. I changed Ubuntu themes but borders are still not visible. I want them to be visible. How can I solve this?

Comment: may be some code or pictures will help...

Comment: I tried GroupBoxs demo in Qt Examples

Comment: KDE or Gnome? Or some other desktop manager? Did you tried `-style=` argument with Qt example (or simply change style in code with `QApplication::setStyle("motif")`)?

Comment: Gnome. When I change style with code borders are visible. Thanks.
Answer the question with same content I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
QApplication::setStyle("motif");
```